# SSRS report (rdlc) value expression and null checking

Tags: reporting-services, null, ssrs-2008

Just wondering if the following expressions used for Value are equivalent (the column "Contrib" in DataSet "MyDataSet" is nullable) :

option 1 :

```
=Format(First(Fields!Contrib.Value, "MyDataSet"), "C2")
```

option 2 :

```
=IIF(First(Fields!Contrib.Value, "MyDataSet") Is Nothing, "", Format(First(Fields!Contrib.Value, "MyDataSet"), "C2"))
```

i.e. does SSRS have special processing, so that in option 1, it internally checks for a null value, and effectively ends up doing something similar to option 2. From trial and error, they seem to give the same results (when "Contrib" is null/not null), but just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experence Reporting Services will by default output a blank value if the value is Null.

As you are using IIF to modify results I think your issue may be similar to a problem that I have with preventing divide by zero errors on calculated columns.

The IIF will evaluate all of it's operands so an error will occur even if the divide by zero occurs in "false" part. I capture a divide by zero by showing "-" in the report and I use a nested IIF to replace the divisor with a value of 1 but this result is never shown in the report.

```
=IIf(Fields!LastYearMonthToDateSales.Value = 0, "-", (Fields!ThisYearMonthToDateSales.Value - Fields!LastYearMonthToDateSales.Value) / Abs(IIf(Fields!LastYearMonthToDateSales.Value = 0, 1, Fields!LastYearMonthToDateSales.Value)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I had problem with **negative numbers**, I Solved it using `Math.Abs((Sum(Fields!Amount.Value))`